# How do I tune a Bandsaw so the blade doesn't drift?

Tags: tools, woodworking, bandsaw

I just bought a 9-inch Delta bandsaw and I know there are some things you have to do to get it tuned right so the blade doesn't drift etc., but I have no idea what those are.  What are some tips I should follow to get this tuned correctly?

Answer (score 3):

The users manual for the saw should have all the information you need to get the saw setup. This is important because each model of saw will have different guidelines. If it is new saw such manual should have been in the box with the unit.

For a used saw that you purchased at some auction, sale or craig's listing there was not likely a users manual delivered with the unit.  :^(

There is help available on line though. Do a search on "Delta Bandsaw Users Manual" will turn up a good bit of information.

One link I found was [here](http://powertool.manualsonline.com/manuals/mfg/delta/delta_saw_product_list.html).

Key items that they list that would be applicable to band saws:

- Ensure the blade is the correct length
- Make sure the teeth are pointing in the right direction (up/down) when blade is installed.
- Set the tension levers to apply tension to the blade
- Hand rotate the tires that the blade rotates on to see if the blade tracks and centers.
- If there problem then check the blade tension and adjust if necessary
- Finally if the blade seems to want to come off the wheels it will be necessary adjust the coplanarity of the wheels to make sure that they are correct.

Answer (score 0):

he best way is to get it running correctly and there should not be any drift.

Follow this **THE BEST FROM A BANDSAW** 'Alex Snodgrass of Carter Industries has an excellent video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wGbZqWac0jU  on a tune up method that works well, but if you want to get the best use of your bandsaw on an ongoing basis, then the Steve Maskery DVD's will show you far more and they are a real investment.   http://www.workshopessentials.com/shop/ '.

My bandsaw (Record BS400) works like a dream.

Malcolm
www.badgerwoodcrafters.co.uk